# Cannot get posts of subscriptions in neo4j

Tags: mysql, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-ogm

I have a requirement where I have to get posts of users whom I have subscribed but something seems to be wrong here:

Final query returns nothing but when I run the parts separately I get results:

```
I get results when I use separately
user_0 subscribed to user_7 and user 7 has many posts
match (u:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [r:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (u2:USER) return u2,u,r limit 10
match (u:USER {name: 'user_7'}) <- [r:CREATED_POST] - (p:POSTS) return p,u,r limit 50
```

```
Final query: 0 results ,Extremely slow queries runs for 115 seconds and gets nothing
match (:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (:USER) -- (p:POSTS) return p limit 100
OR
match (:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (:USER) <- [:CREATED_POST] - (p:POSTS) return p limit 100
```

How can I combine query and make it faster. USER(name) is index and POSTS(name) also.

Is there any other database that can get it done faster ? I am using it in docker.
I used mysql but it slows down after I raise number of subscriptions.

```
Neo4j test db
Users: 1 million
Subcriptions per user: 200
Posts per user : 150
```

Pofiling output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzgYY.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMjWW.png

Comment: PROFILE Match (:USER {name: 'user_0'})-[:SUBSCRIBED_TO]->(:USER)<-[:CREATED_POST]-(p:POSTS) return p limit 100, can you try profiling your query and see what comes up?

Comment: Pofiling output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzgYY.png

Comment: match (u:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (:USER) <- [:CREATED_POST] - (p:POSTS) return p limit 100, try this in your initial query since you not stored the filtered user by name, the search starts from the POSTS nodes, which is not what we want

Comment: completed in 92 seconds but still no results.

Comment: Can you profile the above query as well?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMjWW.png

Comment: Check the 4th stage of the profile output,seems like the `user` with name `user_0` isn't subscribed to any other user, that's why number of rows forwarded by that stage is 0

Comment: But when I run this query in two parts , I can see the user_0 has subscribed to many users. Can it be something else ?

Comment: In the queries with parts, I see to fetch posts you are looking for `user_7`, is that user linked to `user_0`?

Comment: yes user_0 is subscribed_to user_7. I ran first query to get any user which user_0 subscribed.

Comment: Try these two queries: 
1.  `match (u:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (:USER{name: 'user_7'}) <- [:CREATED_POST] - (p:POSTS) return p limit 100`
This will tell us whether the query is right or not.
2. `MATCH (u:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (u2:USER{name: 'user_7'}) 
   MATCH (u2)<- [:CREATED_POST] - (p:POSTS) return p limit 100`
Try spitting into two match statements, to see if something comes up. Make sure the directions of the relationships are correct.

Comment: match (u1:USER {name: 'user_0'}) - [:SUBSCRIBED_TO] -> (u2:USER {name: 'user_7'}) return u2, u1 limit 10
gave 2 results because both users are subscribed to each other.
Still query took near 100 seconds

Comment: I don't understand the braces and brackets; please provide a sample query with just strings.

Comment: Hey @AbhayRawat, if possible can you add a subset of your data here http://console.neo4j.org/, and share the unique link, it will be helpful in debugging the issue